# Why does the Arzela-Ascoli theorem assume each $f_n$ is continuous, if equicontinuity implies it anyway?

Tags: real-analysis

Here's the statement of Arzela-Ascoli in Rudin's PMA:

If $K$ is compact, if $f_n \in \mathscr{C}(K)$ for $n = 1, 2, 3, ....$, and if $\{f_n\}$ is pointwise bounded and equicontinuous on $K$, then

(a) $\{f_n\}$ is uniformly bounded on $K$,

(b) $\{f_n\}$ contains a uniformly convergent subsequence.

Question: Why should we assume $f_n \in \mathscr{C}{(K)}$ (the set of continuous functions on $K$), when equicontinuity implies it anyway?

Comment: Because the author wants to stress on the fact that the sequence is in the set $\mathscr C(K)$, rather than being a generic sequence of functions that ends up being there by accident.

Comment: Stating the whole theorem in the context of $\mathscr C(K)$ also helps to emphasize that the limit of the subsequence in (b) will be continuous.